# Flatten a tiled array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a tiled numpy array of shape (16, 32, 16, 16), that is each tile is 16x16 pixels in a grid 32 tiles wide and 16 high.

From here I want to reshape it to a 256 high x 512 wide 2D image, and I can't quite find the right incantation of splits, slices, and reshapes to get to what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine numpy's reshape and transpose to get this job done. I am not entirely sure which of the three "16"s belongs to the 32x16 repetition grid, but assuming it's the first one:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.random((16, 32, 16, 16))
# put number of repetitions next to respective dimension
transposed_data = np.transpose(data, (0, 2, 1, 3))
# concatenate repeated dimensions via reshape
reshaped_data = transposed_data.reshape((16 * 16, 32 * 16))
print(reshaped_data.shape)
```

Comment: That's it! I was missing the transpose(). Thanks Christian.